# Set Column heading by binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

i have a simple class where I collect some data. 
The first "row" includes the title (ID, Name, etc.) as string.
In my WPF project I have a DataGrid and the follwoing XAML code:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="12,12,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding uID}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding uFName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Second Name" Binding="{Binding uSName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

But I need to delete the first row of my data. It is possible to use the first row of my data collection as column heading an not by a fix XAML?

Comment: I assume `Entries` is a list of some class? Whatever it is, create a DataTable with columns based on your first row, add rows to it based on the other rows, and expose that as the property Entries.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to use the first row of my data collection as column heading an not by a fix XAML?

You could do this using a `HeaderTemplate`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding uID}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items[0].uID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```